# Adding DOM bloat when displaying flash message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

In my Rails application, when a user saves, it uses Ajax to save the post and then execute the update.js.erb file. In that file, I have some jQuery:

```
$('body').append('<div class="message">Saved</div>');
```

Because I have it this way, every time the user saves, it adds more `<div class="message">Saved</div>` in the body. Is there a way I can stop that or does it not matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lazy (but easy) method would be to clear the other messages before showing your new one:

```
$('.message').remove();
$('body').append('<div class="message">Saved</div>');
```

Comment: Ah, you genius. Why didn't I think of that! :) Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't say this is lazy! It would be worth storing your .message divs in a container and then emptying this container when a new one is shown.

Answer (score 0):

First off, unless the save is happening thousands of times, it probably doesn't matter.  Remeber that images are very large so a few kb of extra text in a web page pales in comparison to a few images.

Second, you have several options to only ever have one of these in the DOM:

1. After showing it to the user, then remove it from the DOM (perhaps on a timer).
2. Have one and only one message and show/hide it when needed (this is probably simplest).
3. Look to see if one is already in the page and reuse it.

For example, to find a previous message object (that starts out hidden) and show it for a brief period of time, you could use this:

```
$(".message").html("Saved").show().delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
```

If you used that, you would just put the message object in your page once to start with, either in the original page HTML or just append it once in your page startup code.  Then, have CSS that defaults it to hidden so it only shows when you want it to.

Or, if you're using a CSS3 transition based on a class name, you can do just use jQuery's `addClass()` and `removeClass()`.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to have 'clean' code. I've used the answer above which is to remove it and then add it again, similar to your 1st option. Thanks!

Comment: @user1919937 - it's technically better practice (to learn in general) to reuse a single message object rather than destroying and recreating every time you want to use one.  That was what I added code for.

Comment: The only thing is that I use CSS to fade it in and fade it out using a class, I don't think I can recreate it in jQuery can I?

Comment: @user1919937 - sure, you can use jQuery's `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` to trigger a CSS3 transition based on that class.

Comment: So would it be `$('.message').html("Saved").addClass('success').delay(2000).removeClass('success');`?

Comment: Hmm, it's not working. Do you have an idea of how I can do it?

Comment: @user1919937 - in jQuery, you can only use other animations with `.delay()`.  This is a case where it's not easy to mix CSS3 with jQuery.  You can see both the mix of jQuery and CSS and just plain jQuery here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Ccjtn/.  Keep in mind the CSS3 way doesn't work in IE9 and earlier.